# Luigi framework crash

Tags: python, crash, luigi

when I running luigi tasks, sometimes will meet framework crash, cause the following tasks all failed. Here the error log info:

```
2017-10-05 22:02:02,564 luigi-interface WARNING  Failed pinging scheduler
2017-10-05 22:02:03,129 requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool INFO     Starting new HTTP connection (126): localhost
2017-10-05 22:02:03,130 luigi-interface ERROR    Failed connecting to remote scheduler 'http://localhost:8082'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    File "/home/develop/data_warehouse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    File "/home/develop/data_warehouse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 467, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8082): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/add_worker (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f15128cb3d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
2017-10-05 22:02:03,180 luigi-interface INFO     Worker Worker(salt=150908931, workers=3, host=etl2, username=develop, pid=18019) was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "app_metadata.py", line 1567, in <module>
    luigi.run()
    File "/home/develop/data_warehouse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/interface.py", line 210, in run
    return _run(*args, **kwargs)['success']
    File "/home/develop/data_warehouse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/interface.py", line 238, in _run
    return _schedule_and_run([cp.get_task_obj()], worker_scheduler_factory)
    File "/home/develop/data_warehouse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/interface.py", line 197, in _schedule_and_run
    success &= worker.run()
    File "/home/develop/data_warehouse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 867, in run
    self._add_worker()
    File "/home/develop/data_warehouse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 652, in _add_worker
    self._scheduler.add_worker(self._id, self._worker_info)
    File "/home/develop/data_warehouse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/rpc.py", line 219, in add_worker
    return self._request('/api/add_worker', {'worker': worker, 'info': info})
    File "/home/develop/data_warehouse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/rpc.py", line 146, in _request
    page = self._fetch(url, body, log_exceptions, attempts)
    File "/home/develop/data_warehouse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/rpc.py", line 138, in _fetch
    last_exception
    luigi.rpc.RPCError: Errors (3 attempts) when connecting to remote scheduler 'http://localhost:8082'
```

**sounds like try to ping central schedule, but be failed, then crashed, later tasks all be blocked, cannot run successfully.**

and, some one else also meet the similar error, but his resolution not works.
[Github - Failed connecting to remote scheduler #1894](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/1894)

Comment: It could be that you are not running the central scheduler but your task is trying to connect to it since you didn't provide the --local-scheduler flag.

Answer (score 2):

I would try making the timeout a little longer if your central scheduler is getting overloaded. You could also increase retries and retry wait time.

in luigi.cfg

```
[core]
rpc-connect-timeout=60.0 #default is 10.0
rpc-retry-attempts=10    #default is 3
rpc-retry-wait=60        #default is 30
```

You may also want to add a watch have the scheduler process automatically restart on crash.

Comment: how to check the status of the scheduler process automatically, to read and parse log info?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the central scheduler properly? See the docs:
https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/central_scheduler.html

If not, try using the local scheduler by specifying `--local-scheduler` from the command line.